# NServiceBus send fails silently when remote queue does not exist

Tags: nservicebus

Using NServiceBus 4.4.2.

When sending to a local recipient and before the Recipient got a chance to run (meaning queues are not there yet) I get a nice exception 'The destination queue "xyz" could not be found'. However, when sending to a recipient on another machine, and Remote recipient hasn't run yet (remote queues are not there yet), there is no exception thrown, no error anywhere on the sender and message is nowhere to be found.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is in the "Outgoing Queues"

[image]

MSMQ uses  store-and-forward to reliably send messages to remote queues.
In this case because the remote queue is not available yet, the message will stay in the outgoing queue till either expires or the remote queue becomes available.

Comment: Also, if the message could not be delivered, it will be moved to the dead letter queue under System Queues (unless you configure NServiceBus to turn off that behavior).

Comment: It appears that DLQ is turned. Messages are still in the outgoing queue after 12h. Is it true that TTL by default is 4 days and that TTL can be set only via attribute per message? Also, how would one find out a TTL of a message that is waiting in outgoing or is already in DLQ. I don't seem find an indicator of TTL in message properties.

Comment: Thank you all for speedy and accurate help!